# How to know if NSAssert is disabled in release builds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I often saw "assert " in iOS code, I google it, and got to know it assert true or false.

I want to know if this will auto disable in release mode?

Comment: It is, frankly, a crazy design that asserts aren't turned off in release builds by default. Flies in the face of every other C compiler I know of.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Agree, we got a shock when Assertions still came through in Release.  Completely unconventional.  Our philosophy is 'fail fast in development, die hard in production'.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use NSAssert() and its companions.

in the project define `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` for your release configuration.

Xcode 4 tremplates disable `NSAsserts` in the release configuration. It adds

```
-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1
```

to "Other C Flags" for "Release".

From the documentation:

Assertions are disabled if the preprocessor macro `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is defined.

The NSAssert macro evaluates the condition and serves as a front end to the assertion handler.

Each thread has its own assertion handler, which is an object of class `NSAssertionHandler`. When invoked, an assertion handler prints an error message that includes the method and class names (or the function name). It then raises an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception. If condition evaluates to NO, the macro invokes `handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:` on the assertion handler for the current thread, passing desc as the description string.

This macro should be used only within Objective-C methods.

Answer (score 52):

**Update:** Verified this works in Xcode 8 as well.

In Xcode 7, go into the project build settings and search for "Assert" in the search bar. This shows section "Apple LLVM 7.0 - Preprocessing" section. There is a setting named "Enable Foundation Assertions".

I have successfully enabled/disabled NSAssert from there.

[image]

Comment: that adds a `ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS = NO;` flag to the `AppName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file of the app

Answer (score 36):

I will here provide a meta-answer:

Both @CocoaFu and @dasblinkenlight are correct. `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` turns off `NSAssert()` and `NDEBUG` turns off `assert()`. You need both if you use both.

Comment: Reading iOS 5 Programming by @Rob: Get it, Read it, Program better in iOS 5.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your summary of the two words you spelt one wrongly.

Comment: Noted and fixed. NSDEBUG->NDEBUG

Comment: NDEBUG=1 should be added to Preprocessor Macros section, not to the Other C Flags

Comment: @NAlexN You can pass it to Other C Flags but it would take the form `-DNDEBUG=1`, using -D to specify a macro definition.

Answer (score 8):

As Zaph said `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1` is set for release.  However, if you wanted to check this.

First observe in the docs that [NSAssert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert) is disabled by the macro `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS`.  Then add this to the build and observe it complies ok:

```
#ifdef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
#error Error - NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS is defined
#endif
```

Then change the scheme to release (cmd - shift - <)

[image]

Then observe that the build fails.  Therefore `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is defined meaning `NSAssert`s are disabled.

Answer (score 5):

Asserts are conditionally compiled out of your code when `NDEBUG` is defined. If you define `NDEBUG=1` in the corresponding build settings section, you will deactivate asserts in your code regardless of the release or debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do at the top of my `main()`:

```
#if defined(NDEBUG)
{
  // The assertion code below should be compiled out of existence in a release
  // build.  Log an error and abort the program if it is not.
  bool ok = true;
  NSCAssert(ok = false, @"NS assertions should be disabled but are not");
  if (!ok)
  {
    NSLog(@"Detected release build but NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS is not defined");
    return -1;
  }
}
#endif
```

Note that since `main()` is a C function and not an Objective-C function, `NSCAssert` is used above rather than `NSAssert`. (`NSAssert` expects `self` to be valid.)

Answer (score 1):

Now, as of Xcode 6, the setting is `ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS`, which is set to `1` for Debug configurations and `0` for Release, by default.

You can opt into it for Release builds on the command line by passing the `ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS=1` argument, which I'm doing for running unit tests that check for assertion conditions, but otherwise should run with the `DEBUG` flag off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift package manager, you'll need to disable assertions at the target level. Packages don't pick up the build settings from your Xcode project.

```swift
.target(
    name: "ObjcPackage",
    dependencies: [],
    path: "include",
    cxxSettings: [.define("NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS", .when(configuration: release))]
),
```