# NSAssert(boolean) in release

Tags: objective-c

Simple question.

If I have

```
BOOL a = [myInst function];
NSAssert(a, @"...")
```

then I will get warnings in the release build because a is not used. I want to assert a BOOL returned from a function, but I don't need to use it. How would I fix it?

I can't put the whole expression into NSAssert because it won't compile in release.

Comment: Sorry you'll have to rephrase your question as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: With `#pragma unused(x,y,z)` you can tell the compiler that `x`, `y` and `z` aren't used; though I've only used that for function arguments and only with GCC, it might work for variables.  This would have to appear inside an `#ifdef` that determines when `NSAssert()` is disabled (`#ifndef DEBUG` perhaps?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the expression which results in `a` does not have side-effects, why not put it directly into `NSAssert`? E.g.

```
NSAssert(<expr>, @"...")
```

Note that if `<expr>` has side-effects, e.g. prints something, this may not happen in non-Debug builds.

Comment: I can't because I want to assert results directly from a function.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

<your function>

#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wunused-variable"
```

Answer (score 2):

I dislike that warning.

Here is what I do in these cases:

```
BOOL a = NO;
a = [myInst function];
NSAssert(a, @"...")
```

Comment: I got rid of that warning completely using this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Just mention the BOOL one more time:

```
a = !(!a);
```

or

```
if (a) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [How to know if NSAssert is disabled in release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552486/how-to-know-if-nsassert-is-disabled-in-release-builds), you can use `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` to know if NSAssert is being overridden to do nothing.

Therefore, you can define your own assertion macro:

```
#ifdef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
    #define ABCAssert(condition, ...) \
        do { \
            if (!condition) \
                NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); \
        } while (0)
#else
    #define ABCAssert(condition, ...) NSAssert(condition, __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Now replace all calls to NSAssert, with ABCAssert. In addition to ensuring that condition is always used, it will log any assertion failures rather than silently ignoring them.

Warning: I haven't tested the code above. When I have more time I will update it to ensure it works properly.

---

This is similar to [Abizer Nasir's coding conventions](http://abizern.org/cocoa-coding-conventions/#standard-files) which defines:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define ALog(...) [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__]
#else
  #ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
    #define NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
  #endif
  #define ALog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#endif
```

There are a few differences, though:

- We retain the first option, `condition`, which will determine if the assertion should fail or not.
- Instead of hard-coding to disable it during DEBUG, it uses the existing `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` macro which can be [customized based on your project's target settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377845/xcode-5-equivalent-of-ns-block-assertions-in-build-settings).
- Also note that because NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS is being defined programmatically, this means that Nasir's code must be placed before the [Cocoa and Foundation imports in the pch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445429/35690).