# Xcode 5 equivalent of NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS in Build Settings

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, build, xcode5, compiler-flags

Until Xcode 5, Release builds could be prevented from including `NSAssert` statements and their variants, using the default Build Setting:

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = "-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1";
```

This setting can be found in `project.pbxproj` and is set in Xcode here:

[image]

*(Note that this grab was taken from an Xcode 4 project converted to Xcode 5.)*

Each target would inherit this setting in the Release build only. Obviously this was a good thing. Rather than crash immediately, the app would possibly struggle on regardless. Whereas for Debug builds, you want to know immediately when an `NSAssert` fails.

However, I am struggling to find the equivalent in Xcode 5.

Creating a new project using the default templates shows no equivalent setting:

[image]

My question is, what is the equivalent setting in Xcode 5, or does `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` have to be added manually to `Other C Flags` for the Release build?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's got it's own setting field now! **Enable Foundation Assertions**. Set your debug as yes and your release as no, as shown in screen grab below.

[image]

Note: You need to click All in the top left in your build settings tab to see it, you can see in my screen grab the blue ALL in the top left.

Comment: The plot thickens. From experimentation, the new flag in Xcode 5 - "Enable Foundation Assertions" or ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS - does appear to work. However, if you examine NSException.h, it still checks against the previous flag NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS. See #if !defined(NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS) (from http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Oct/msg00134.html).