# In Xcode, why is Enable Foundation Assertions set to YES by default?

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, assert

In Xcode, why is Enable Foundation Assertions set to YES by default for all builds, including Release? Is Apple advocating/recommend that we ship with asserts?

Comment: This flag is in the preprocessing settings, no? Would it not matter then?

Comment: It matters - that means your assertion will go out in your release build by default if you don't pay attention.

Comment: what do you wanna hear? that it is a bade idea? Or not? (I mean ... I would say: leave valid assertions in)

Comment: write a custom assertionHandler if you want... like xcode does

Comment: @Boon Apparently, but in projects updated from Xcode 4.x, the original [Compiler flags are kept](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20377845/620197). Easy to overlook for new projects.

Comment: @Daji-Djan Read the second part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike answered in the comments: *"Apparently, but in projects updated from Xcode 4.x, the original Compiler flags are kept. Easy to overlook for new projects."*