# Building the test target fails with this error "This project requires NS_Block_Assertions to be undefined

Tags: earlgrey

Trying to get started with EarlGrey , i followed the steps to manually add EarlGrey to the project . But every time i try to build the test target it tends to fail with this error

/EarlGrey-1.0.0/EarlGrey.pch:27:4: "This project requires NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS to be undefined."

Anyone else ran into this problem and have suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the recent versions of EarlGrey. Consider updating to the [most recent 1.4.0 release](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/releases)

Comment: Thank you , The latest did helo

Answer (score 0):

You can enable this in Xcode for the version of your app that you plan to test using EarlGrey, see this for how you can do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20378159/5971511

Comment: Thanks for this tip too . I did try this but didnt help for some reason on Xcode 8.0 . Moving to the recent release did help