# What's the safe and elegant way to check for nil before calling a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dry

I'm working on an API which includes a lot of block arguments with its interface. I decided the library should accept `nil` for block arguments. So it is necessary to check for `nil` before calling any block in the implementation.

However, the code would become quite ugly if there is a lot of `if`.

```
if (completionHandler) {
    completionHandler(userInfo, success, error)
}
```

one line of code would become 3 lines.

I'm currently using such a macro definition to avoid this,

```
#define completionHandler(...) if (completionHandler) completionHandler(__VA_ARGS__)
```

It works well. But this technique limits the name of my callbacks to `"completionHandler"`. Is there an more elegant and also safe way to support arbitrary callback names?

Does any one have any suggestions on `nil` checking?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054024/which-is-the-best-way-to-check-method-arguments-in-objective-c

Comment: You can make the block name the first parameter of the macro: `#define iff(completionHandler, ...) if (completionHandler) completionHandler(__VA_ARGS__)` and then `iff(completionHandler, success, error);`

Answer (score 0):

One option which does it in one line and completely abuses operators is:

```
completionHandler && ( completionHandler(userInfo,success,error) , YES )
```

I'd recommend steering clear of using macros for that. Generally, macros *can* improve readability, except that you are adding what look like primitives to the vocabulary of your application and confuses things.

You also don't have to put the `{ }`:

```
if (completionHandler) completionHandler(userInfo,success,error) ;
```

Comment: I agree with iAdjunct. In your case, using a macro will cut down on the readability of your code and make debugging a pain. Honestly, in my opinion the three line solution you are trying to minimize is the clearest and most readable way of handling calling a block.