# What is NSAssert1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsassert

I am developing an application on iOS. I see there is a macro called `NSAssert1`. What is it for? What are the differences in usage between `NSLog` and `NSAssert1`?

Please guide me or suggest a tutorial where I can read about it.

Comment: Here is a post about that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375786/whats-the-point-of-nsassert-actually

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the point of NSAssert, actually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375786/whats-the-point-of-nsassert-actually)

Comment: most likely sends meta data to the NSA

Answer (score 29):

`NSAssert` variants take a condition and a message.  If the condition isn't met/true, then the assertion fails and NSAssert raises an exception with the message provided.  For example, `NSAssert((a == b), @"Error message");` will raise an exception when `a` is not equal to `b`.  `NSAssert1` is a variant that takes an additional argument and inserts it into the format string provided, like so: `NSAssert1((a == b), @"Error message: %@", someErrorString);`

`NSLog` will just write something to the console.

Documentation for all of those macros is [on Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsassert?language=occ).

Comment: But why couldn't they just have the one function that handled the arguments like `[NSString stringWithFormat:....]`, why have 5 extra variants of `NSAssert`? I know you're not Apple, but just wondering if anyone knows.

Comment: Ahhhh: "In order to provide the method and line number information, the NSAssert() routine must be implemented as a macro, and therefore to handle different numbers of arguments to the format string, there are 5 assertion macros for methods: NSAssert(condition, description), NSAssert1(condition, format, arg1), NSAssert2(condition, format, arg1, arg2), …, NSAssert5(…)." - http://mike.rssmemo.com/?p=40

Comment: nil has provided example of A and B. But, the same could have achieved with `If` condition too. What is the difference between If and `NSAssert` ?

Comment: Also important to note that NSAssert will generally *not* raise an exception in release builds; though this depends on the release configuration.

Answer (score 5):

`NSAssert`, `NSParameterAssert`, `NSAssert1`, and friends are assertion macros. Assertions are condition checks that scream when something is not right:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithPointer: (Foo*) foo
{
    NSAssert(foo != NULL, @"The Foo pointer must not be NULL!");
    foo->something;
}
```

See [questions tagged “assertions”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions) here on Stack Overflow for more information.