# NSAssert undeclared first use why?

Tags: iphone, ios, archive, llvm, nsassert

i used the code below in the `levelManager.m` to read values from a plist but when I am making an Archive to upload to itunes (AppStore) I get an error. why ?

the code :

```
- (float)floatForProp:(NSString *)prop {
NSNumber * retval = (NSNumber *) [_curStage objectForKey:prop];
NSAssert (retval != nil, @"Couldn't find prop %@", prop);
return retval.floatValue;
}
```

the error:

NSAssert undeclared first use

Note I notice that xcode is thinking that I am giving NSAssert 3 parameters  instead of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the `NSAssert` variants, in your case `NSAssert1`:

```
#define NSAssert1(condition, desc, arg1)
```

So:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

- (float)floatForProp:(NSString *)prop
{
  NSNumber * retval = (NSNumber *) [_curStage objectForKey:prop];
  NSAssert1 (retval != nil, @"Couldn't find prop %@", prop);
  return retval.floatValue;
}
```

Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496378/iphone-what-is-nsassert1) of interest and Apple's [Assertions and Logging Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Assertions/Assertions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000014-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with

```
NSAssert (retval != nil, ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Couldn't find prop %@", prop]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think its thinking you are giving three parameters, use this:

```
NSAssert (retval != nil, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Couldn't find prop %@", prop]);
```