# NSAssert vs. assert: Which do you use, and when?

Tags: objective-c, assert

I've read two really interesting pieces of advice, recently:

1. In the comments to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375786/whats-the-point-of-nsassert-actually/1375819#1375819), @Mike Weller says to leave your asserts on in production code... what's the performance hit, really? Is there any reason NOT to leave them in?
2. In [Vincent Gable's blog](http://vgable.com/blog/2008/12/04/nsassert-considered-harmful/), he states that you should prefer `assert` over `NSAssert`... is there any reason NOT to use `assert`? (it's less letters :))

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. There should be very little performance hit for leaving in an assertion, unless the actual action in the assertion is time consuming (e.g. `assert([obj calculateMeaningOfLife] == 42)`).  An assertion should be no different than an extra `if` statement, performance-wise.  The reason for stripping out assertions in release builds is that they are essentially a debugging tool--they catch inconsistent internal program state at runtime. From a developer perspective, it's much better for an app to crash as soon as something goes wrong, but from a user perspective it's arguably less annoying if the app doesn't crash (unless letting the app run with abnormal state causes something horrible to happen), and exposing development details in error messages can be off-putting. There are good arguments on both sides--if I remember correctly, *Code Complete* recommends stripping them out but *The Pragmatic Programmer* recommends leaving them in.  In any  case, assertions are not a substitute for proper error handling and should only be used for programming errors.
2. The basic difference between an `NSAssert` and a regular `assert` is that an `NSAssert` raises an exception when it fails while an `assert` just crashes the app.  `NSAssert` also lets you supply fancier error messages and logs them.  Practically, I really don't think there's much difference between the two--I can't think of a reason to handle an exception thrown by an assertion.  (To split hairs, I think `NSAssert` usually involves less typing because you don't have to include `assert.h`, but that's neither here nor there.)

Comment: One reason you might want assertions to be handled as an exception is to be caught by a crash-reporting tool like Flurry or TestFlight. These work by installing a top-level exception handler, and `assert` failures won't be caught by that.

Comment: With `NSAssert` you can also supply your own error message.

Comment: with `assert()` you don't have to actually return a value if that piece of the control flow

Comment: NSAssert inside a block will cause a self retain and hence can cause retain cycles. This is quite an important point.
See e.g. http://www.takingnotes.co/blog/2011/09/27/making-nsassert-play-nice-with-blocks/

Answer (score 5):

NSAssert() macro should be used only within Objective-C methods.

NSAssert() is disabled if the preprocessor macro NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS is defined (usually in the release version).

Comment: There is NSCAssert for use within C functions.

Comment: Similarly, `assert()` can be disabled by inclusion of `NDEBUG` in preprocessor macro. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/