# Does the NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS disable both NSAssert and assert() calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Does the `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` switch off just the `NSAssert` calls or also the `assert()` calls. My app crashes in the Release mode on the line with `assert(...)` statement.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) says only about `NSAssert` and does not tell if `assert()` calls are being disabled.

There are a couple questions related to mine that are not answering it. I'm linking them here:

[NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445222/ns-block-assertions-in-objective-c)
[NSAssert vs. assert: Which do you use, and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616347/nsassert-vs-assert-which-do-you-use-and-when)
[How to know if NSAssert is disabled in release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552486/how-to-know-if-nsassert-is-disabled-in-release-builds)

Comment: we don't need NS_BLOCK_ASSRETIONS in Swift as all the asserts are valid only it Debug mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `assert()` is controlled with the `NDEBUG` symbol:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(e)   ((void)0)
#else
...
```

(see `/usr/include/assert.h` if you have the Xcode Command Line Tools installed, or elsewhere in the Xcode.app bundle, if not).