# enable Assertions in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, assertions

How to enable `Assertions` in objective?

I have added a third party library which has some `Assertions`. But it does not work. I think `Assertions` are disabled. So I want enable it.

Comment: You need to use [NSAssert](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) for the assertions. Also this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375786/whats-the-point-of-nsassert-actually) will be so useful for you.

Comment: How did you use the `NSAssertion` ?

Comment: I did not use NSAssertion but the library which i added have assertions. I simply need it to enable only. i cant see Assertion while debugging.@MidhunMP

Comment: By default its enabled. right? @MidhunMP

Comment: Yes. In default it is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [NSAssert](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) for the assertions.

The `NSAssertions` are disabled if the `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is specified.

You can use the `NSAssert` like:

```
NSAssert(count != 0, @"Count should be greater than zero");
```